# Parsing XML column in Pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm relatively new to PySpark and trying to solve a data problem. I have a pyspark DF, created with data extracted from MS SQL Server, having 2 columns: ID (Integer) and XMLMsg (String). The 2nd column, XMLMsg contains data in XML format.
The goal is to parse the XMLMsg column and create additional columns in the same DF with the extracted columns from the XML.

Following is a sample structure of the pyspark DF:

```
ID  XMLMsg
101 ...<a><b>name1</b><c>loc1</c></a>...<d>dept1</d>...
102 ...<a><b>name2</b><c>loc2</c></a>...<d>dept2</d>...
103 ...<a><b>name3</b><c>loc3</c></a>...<d>dept3</d>...
```

Expected output is:

```
ID  XMLMsg                                              b       c       d
101 ...<a><b>name1</b><c>loc1</c></a>...<d>dept1</d>... name1   loc1    dept1
102 ...<a><b>name2</b><c>loc2</c></a>...<d>dept2</d>... name2   loc2    dept2
103 ...<a><b>name3</b><c>loc3</c></a>...<d>dept3</d>... name3   loc3    dept3
```

I tried few suggestions based on my search in SO; however, could not achieve the expected result. Hence, reaching out for some help and directions. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this finally using Lambda and UDF considering i had to get the texts from 4 nodes from a huge XML file. Since the XML files are already in a column and part of the pyspark Dataframe, I didnt want to write as files and again parse the whole XML. I also wanted to avoid using XSD schema.
The actual xml has multiple namespaces and also some nodes with specific conditions.
Example:

```
<ap:applicationproduct xmlns:xsi="http://www.example.com/2005/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ap="http://example.com/productinfo/1_6" xmlns:ct="http://example.com/commontypes/1_0" xmlns:dc="http://example.com/datacontent/1_0" xmlns:tp="http://aexample.com/prmvalue/1_0" ....." schemaVersion="..">
  <ap:ParameterInfo>
    <ap:Header>
      <ct:Version>1.0</ct:Version>
      <ct:Sender>ABC</ct:Sender>
      <ct:SenderVersion />
      <ct:SendTime>...</ct:SendTime>
    </ap:Header>
    <ap:ProductID>
      <ct:Model>
        <ct:Series>34AP</ct:Series>
        <ct:ModelNo>013780</ct:ModelNo>
     ..............
      ..............
   <ap:Object>
        <ap:Parameter schemaVersion="2.5" Code="DDA">
          <dc:Value>
            <tp:Blob>mbQAEAgBTgKQEBAX4KJJYABAIASL0AA==</tp:Blob>
          </dc:Value>
        </ap:Parameter>
.........
........
```

Here I need to extract the values from ct:ModelNo and tp:Blob

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
# List of namespaces to be used:
ns = {'ap' : 'http://example.com/productinfo/1_6', 
'ct':'http://example.com/commontypes/1_0', 
'dc':'http://example.com/datacontent/1_0', 
'tp':'http://aexample.com/prmvalue/1_0' 
    }

parsed_model = (lambda x:    ET.fromstring(x).find('ap:ParameterInfo/ap:ProductID/ct:Model/ct:ModelNo', ns).text)
udf_model = udf(parsed_model)
parsed_model_df = df.withColumn('ModelNo', udf_Model('XMLMsg'))
```

Also for the Node with blob value similar function can be written but the path to the node would be:
'ap:ParameterInfo/ap:Object/ap:Parameter[@Code="DDA"]/dc:Value/tp:Blob'

This worked for me and I was able to add the required values in the pyspark DF. Any suggestions are welcome to make it better though. Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain the namespace and how that plays into your answer?